# do something after keypress (but waiting a little bit)

Tags: java, android, keypress

I need do something (a search in a relatively big ArrayList, then display it in a custom and kinda complex adapter) ONE second after a keypress event, but if another keypress event occur, then I should reset the countdown and wait another second.

Can I do this in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use handlers for that:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();     

private Runnable actionRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
        // your action here
    }
}; 

private void handleKeypress() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(actionRunnable);
    handler.postDelayed(actionRunnable, 1000); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a one-shot [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and cancel it with the new key event.

Is this for something similar to an AutoCompleteTextView? I'll assume just adding a "Search" button is not an option.

Comment: Yeah.. I don't want to use a "search" button... But AutoCompleteTextView is a good option...